# The right way to use gevent with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I simplify a complex system of gevent with sqlachemy to a simple [demo code](https://gist.github.com/tonywangcn/6dadbd58d7778063b0c7969f62505537).

Before using of sqlachemy, pymysql is my best choice for communication between MySql and gevent because of its easy and direct usage. But now I feel a little confusing, what's the best way to make the two (gevent and sqlachemy) work efficiently.

In pymysql case, though some "_io.BufferedReader " error would happen, it doesn't affect the INSERT or UPDATE operations.

In sqlalchemy case, it's quite different in the opposite. Much more errors and little success.

After searching around for such errors, some solutions[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gevent/SQLAlchemy/gevent/eGLfR7JV0kk/hg1kicBJeQkJ] for similar error didn't work.

Demo code :

https://gist.github.com/tonywangcn/6dadbd58d7778063b0c7969f62505537

## log of sqlalchemy

```
2017-07-15 07:29:25,930 - log.py - log - 109  - 20291 -  (DummyThread-8) -INFO - {'ip': '112.201.247.130', 'port': 41607, 'types': 0, 'score': 10, 'updatetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 14, 23, 29, 25, 929929)}
2017-07-15 07:29:25,931 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
2017-07-15 07:29:25,931 - log.py - log - 109  - 20291 -  (DummyThread-9) -INFO - ROLLBACK
2017-07-15 07:29:25,931 - pool.py - pool - 696  - 20291 -  (DummyThread-9) -ERROR - Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 687, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 827, in _reset
    self._reset_agent.rollback()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1621, in rollback
    self._do_rollback()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1659, in _do_rollback
    self.connection._rollback_impl()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 703, in _rollback_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 701, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1598, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 793, in rollback
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 767, in _read_ok_packet
    pkt = self._read_packet()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 987, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1021, in _read_bytes
    data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
RuntimeError: reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2255, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 389, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 548, in execute
    uow
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 181, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 835, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 856, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1004, in _read_packet
    recv_data = self._read_bytes(bytes_to_read)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1018, in _read_bytes
    self._sock.settimeout(self._read_timeout)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settimeout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 536, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 227, in insert_data
    sqlhelper.insert(data)
  File "test.py", line 102, in insert
    self.session.commit()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 906, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 461, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 441, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2171, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2291, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 76, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(type_, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2291, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 477, in rollback
    self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True, rollback_ok=True)
  File "/Users/jiang/code/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 285, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
Sat Jul 15 07:29:26 2017 <Greenlet at 0x10853c3d8: insert_data> failed with ResourceClosedError
```

### log of gevent with pymysql

```
    2017-07-15 07:26:39,545 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-1) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
    2017-07-15 07:26:39,545 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-2) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
    2017-07-15 07:26:39,546 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-3) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
    2017-07-15 07:26:39,546 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-4) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
    2017-07-15 07:26:49,651 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-5) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
    2017-07-15 07:26:49,652 - test.py - test - 62  - 20278 -  (DummyThread-6) -ERROR - reentrant call inside <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
```

Comment: This is because you're sharing a single connection across multiple threads without doing any synchronization, not because of gevent specifically, or even SQLAlchemy. If you were to use the `threading` module with just `pymysql`, you'll likely encounter similar errors. The correct solution depends on your situation: if you need to use a single connection (e.g. you need all changes to be in a single transaction), then you need to add synchronization; otherwise, you should create separate connections in different threads.

Comment: @univerio Thanks , you are right. I will do some more test